# How to change my site SharedHosting to Dedicated IP

Tags: ssl, domain-controller

I have a dedicated IP address and there I host three site as

```
site1com

example1.com

example2.com
```

I need to implement SSL for my example1.com site, I purchased a SSL certificate. But I can't activate my SSL , because of the shared hosting.

So I Purchased another IP and I need to change my example1.com this IP..

Am using **Plesk control panel** so how can i proceed to enable the new IP an SSL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

This depends greatly on the version of Plesk you are running. But in general:

Plesk > YourDomain.com > Setup > IP address (it is a dropdown box, if you have more than one IP available)

If you are the owner & administrator of this server, you would first need to add the IP address to the available pool.

This should all also be covered in greater detail within the help documents in your Plesk control panel.

Comment: yes i changed but not shows when i ping to ma server, it showing the old ip :(

Comment: This is an issue with DNS then, not the IP the site is hosted on. Check the DNS entry for the server at a site like checkdns.net and see what it is resolving to, and what DNS servers it uses.